# Visual Studio Code record-dot-preprocessor error

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I am getting the following error:

```
record-dot-preprocessor: runInteractiveProcess: posix_spawnp: illegal operation 
(Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

I have been searching around and could not find what exactly is causing this error. Everything builds just fine, it appears to possibly be an error with VS Code and Haskell Language Server. A little background on the environment:

```
macOS 10.15.7

ghc 8.10.6: installed via homebrew

ghc-options:
- -F -pgmF=record-dot-preprocessor

Project is being built using stack: Version 2.7.3
```

My question is for any help or direction as to what could possibly be the cause of this issue.